# Reinstalling Windows 10 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, reinstall, clean-install

I am sure that sounds like a rather pedantic question, but I had to ask after reading up on "clean install" and "reinstall" options on the internet.

Let's imagine I want to reinstall Windows 10 with a bootable USB flash drive as you do if you have a FreeDOS device. Let's assume you do not have any important files, programs, etc. on the device. You are able to see disk partitions of the Windows 10 you have already installed in Windows Setup on the disk selection step during reinstallation. If I delete these partitions in order to get unallocated space so that I can reinstall Windows 10 on them, is there any difference between this and other "clean" or "reinstall" options that you can do with Windows 10's built-in feature? This option seems to me exactly the same as what Windows 10 will automatically do. Can I get a clarification on that?

Comment: Clean just means Nothing is carried over from the previous w10 installation, does not matter how you accomplish it.

Comment: No difference then. Thank you for clarification!